# Hello-World-grade landscape Android app fails to start (complete code included)

Tags: android, boot

I'm trying to develop a simple Android app, fixed in landscape mode.  I am using Eclipse 1.3, compiling for Android SDK version 7 (OS version 2.1).  When I try to run it in the emulator, it crashes on boot.  (It gets as far as the unlock slider, but shortly after that when trying to launch the application itself, I get "The application Failtest (process com.wcs.failtest) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.".)

Here is main.xml (with the tags escaped so this displays properly):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="480px"
  android:layout_height="320px"
  >
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="96px"
    android:layout_height="320px"
    android:id="@+id/action_menu"
    >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="96px"
      android:layout_height="48px"
      >
      <Button  
        android:layout_width="48px" 
        android:layout_height="48px"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:id="@+id/action_button_11"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is AndroidManifest.xml (again with the tags escaped so this displays properly):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.wcs.failtest"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity android:name=".FailtestActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>
```

And here is FailtestActivity.java:

```
package com.wcs.failtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;

public class FailtestActivity extends Activity {
    private OnClickListener action11Listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button button;
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_button_11);
        button.setOnClickListener(action11Listener);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

I suspect it is something simple I'm overlooking.  What is it?

Comment: If an app crashes, you need to send out the logcat. That usually explains exactly what's going on.

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and see the stack trace associated with your crash. Also, you only need one `android:xmlns` entry, on your root element, not three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //setup button...
```

Comment: Yup, you're using a view (R.id.action_button_11) before you even create your UI. `button` is null, and you're probably getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.  I figured it was something simple like that.